# What training opportunities are there in the UK for UX research?

Tags: research, training

I'm looking for a short (2 days maybe) training course in the UK (preferably London or South East) on how to conduct great depth interviews for UX type research.

What courses are there out there that cover the following?

- questioning and probing techniques such as pyramids and laddering etc.
- how to handle difficult, angry or quiet participants

Comment: Could you further describe your situation? Are you an experienced UX designer or just starting out? Why do you need this training? etc...

Comment: Also, I'll be surprised if you get any solid answers -- I expect this type of thing is learned from years of experience.

Comment: Hi  @JustCurious I'm afraid this isn't a constructive question for our site. There is no correct answer to this, and everytime any new course comes up it would need to be added to this question to keep it valid. This has been summarized better over on [this Meta StackOverflow post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118464/are-questions-asking-for-training-courses-on-some-technology-appropriate-on-stac) about similar questions on other StackExchange sites.

Comment: If you have any specific questions about Depth Interviews then those questions would be appropriate for this site (indeed, I think we'd welcome such questions) so feel free to raise any of those questions here.

Comment: Loren: I am nearer to beginner level, but I'd be interested to look at different levels of courses on offer. I understand the interview procedure and tools but am looking at courses that cover the "soft skills". Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

For **Depth Interviews** - I'd look at at the wider world of qualitative market research and possibly academic research.

I've also taken the word 'moderator' out of the title as I think this confuses 'testing' with 'qualitative research'.

A quick bit of googling finds this course run by the Market Research Society:

*Effective Depth Interviewing*

*The skills for a wide range of qualitative research situations*

http://www.mrs.org.uk/event/course/338